# place html inside php code the right way and that works

Tags: php, html

i am trying to make html works and the right way to place it so it works placing html inside php code

```
<?php echo <td class=\"network\">".$show."</td>;?>
```

Comment: You can do that, but you need to wrap the string in quotes too. `<?php echo "<td class=\"network\">".$show."</td>";?>` - or alternatively you can just echo PHP where needed, like `<td class="network"><?php echo $show; ?></td>` (then you will need to be out of the PHP-block (not inside `<?php ?>`), or syntax errors occur)

Comment: Based on this question and your other comment I think you would benefit from reading through [a simple PHP tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not give the impression that you've really tried much, or researched the issue.

```
<?php echo "<td class=\"network\">".$show."</td>";?>
```

^^ Should work to output HTML tags. (Though invalid as td should exist inside tables.)

Also note you can use different quotes to reduce the need for escaping. E.g.

```
<?php echo '<td class="network">'.$show.'</td>';?>
```

Comment: i don't know much in php dear :) thanks a lot that worked

Comment: i have one like this <?php echo "S".$season."-E".$ep; ?> can you tell me dear how do i make this inside one td element ?